# Pandas map string to int based on value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns :

```
state  total_sales
AL      16714
AR      6498
AZ      107296
CA      33717
```

Now I want to map the strings in state column to int from 1 to N(where N is the no of rows,here 4 ) based on  increasing order of values in total_sales . Result should be stored in another column (say label). That is, wanted a result like this :

```
state  total_sales label
AL      16714         3
AR      6498          4
AZ      107296        1
CA      33717         2
```

Please suggest a vectorised implementation .

Comment: Please show some of your efforts

Comment: @ZdaR : Implemented it with a for loop , but read that loops are not advised for dataframes .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) with cast to `int`:

```
df['label'] = df['total_sales'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
print (df)
  state  total_sales  label
0    AL        16714      3
1    AR         6498      4
2    AZ       107296      1
3    CA        33717      2
```

Answer (score 3):

One option for converting a column of values to integers is  [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html).

This actually groups identical values, which in a case like this, where all values are unique each "group" has only one value.  The resulting object has a `codes` attribute, which is a Numpy array of integers indicating which group each input value is in.

Applied to this problem, if you have

```py
In [12]: data = pd.DataFrame({
             'state': ['AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA'],
             'total_sales': [16714, 6498, 107296, 33717]
         })
```

you can add the label column as described using

```py
In [13]: data['label'] = len(data) - pd.Categorical(data.total_sales, ordered=True).codes
In [14]: print(data)

  state  total_sales  label
0    AL        16714      3
1    AR         6498      4
2    AZ       107296      1
3    CA        33717      2
```

For this example it is not as fast as [jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42330657/3585557) but it has a wide range of applications and it was faster for a larger series I was encoding to integers.  It should be noted that if there are two identical values in the `total_sales` column it will assign them the same label.